# I'm running flume agent on aws instance and not able to receive events from avro sink which is on aws instance to avro source on my local machine?

Tags: flume, flume-ng

this is the error appears on console on my aws instance.

> 2014-08-09 12:22:41,803 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-2) [INFO
>   -org.apache.flume.source.AvroSource.start(AvroSource.java:142)] Starting Avro source fromLocal: { bindAddress:
>   ec2-54-221-143-114.compute-1.amazonaws.com, port: 44444 }...
>           2014-08-09 12:22:42,072 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [WARN - org.apache.flume.sink.AvroSink.start(AvroSink.java:244)] Unable to
>   create avro client using hostname:
>   ec2-54-221-143-114.compute-1.amazonaws.com, port: 41414
>           org.apache.flume.FlumeException: NettyAvroRpcClient { host: ec2-54-221-143-114.compute-1.amazonaws.com, port: 41414 }: RPC
>   connection error
>             at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.connect(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:117)
>             at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.connect(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:93)
>             at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.configure(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:514)
>             at org.apache.flume.api.RpcClientFactory.getInstance(RpcClientFactory.java:88)
>             at org.apache.flume.sink.AvroSink.createConnection(AvroSink.java:182)
>             at org.apache.flume.sink.AvroSink.start(AvroSink.java:242)
>             at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.start(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:46)
>             at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner.start(SinkRunner.java:79)
>             at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:236)
>             at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>           Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error connecting to ec2-54-221-143-114.compute-1.amazonaws.com/10.80.54.114:41414
>             at org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver.getChannel(NettyTransceiver.java:261)
>             at org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver.(NettyTransceiver.java:203)
>             at org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver.(NettyTransceiver.java:152)
>             at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.connect(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:106)
>             ... 15 more
>           Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>             at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
>             at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
>             at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:401)
>             at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:370)
>             at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.run(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:292)

Answer (score 0):

Run flume agent with Avro Source on your local machine first, then run the flume agent with avro sink.
The reason is that Avro Source starts the Avro RPC Server binded at given IP and port. Avro Sink is a avro rpc client that listens to Avro RPC Server and sends the flume events to it.